# matplotlib 3d -- inserting data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, 3d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5nOs.jpg)i am a beginner at programming. I started like 2 months ago so please be patient with me :-) 
So i want to make a 3d surface plot with matplotlib on python 3.4.

i watched a lot of tutorials about this but i didnt find something exactly like what i need to do..i hope you can help me.
In all the videos they give with meshgrid a relation between the 3 axis(x, y, z) but i dont want that.what i want to do is this:
i have 16 sensors and they are placed on 4 rows with 4 sensors each so in the fisrt row are 1,2,3,4 and the second 5,6,7,8 and so on..(the order of sensors is very important).for example Sensor Number 4 = 200 from a skala from 0 until 800..i thought of using x and y axis only for the correct location in the graph..for example with sensor 4(=200 from 800) is placed in the first row in the forth column...so..x=4 and y=1 and z=200 from 800 like before.so in the end every sensor has only one 'real' value..z..

how can i import this kind of data with matplotlib for all 16 sensor to make a 3d plot?? i would really appreciate any kind of help..

Comment: Can you try to clear up your explanation? I'm not following. What is meant by the line: `Sensor Number 4 = 200 from a skala from 0 until 800`

Comment: You first have to understand what kind of data you have, do you have three 1D arrays, tuples with 3 elements, ...?

Comment: i mean that z can take values from 0 to 800 and in this example it was 400.

Comment: I hope now that i uploaded the pisture that you can understand what i mean!!Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start somewhere. So let's say the data is a list of 16 values. You can then create a 2D array of it and show that array as an image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# input data is a list of 16 values, 
# the first value is of sensor 1, the last of sensor 16
input_data = [200,266,350,480,
              247,270,320,511,
              299,317,410,500,
              360,360,504,632]
# create numpy array from list and reshape it to a 4x4 matrix
z = np.array(input_data).reshape(4,4)
# at this point you can already show an image of the data
plt.imshow(z)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

An option to now plot the values as height in a 3D plot instead of color in a 2D plot would be to use a `bar3d` plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# input data is a list of 16 values, 
# the first value is of sensor 1, the last of sensor 16
input_data = [200,266,350,480,
              247,270,320,511,
              299,317,410,500,
              360,360,504,632]

# create a coordinate grid
x,y = np.meshgrid(range(4), range(4))

ax = plt.gcf().add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
#plot the values as 3D bar graph
# bar3d(x,y,z, dx,dy,dz) 
ax.bar3d(x.flatten(),y.flatten(),np.zeros(len(input_data)), 
         np.ones(len(input_data)),np.ones(len(input_data)),input_data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You may also plot a surface plot, but in that case the grid will define the edges of the surface tiles.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# input data is a list of 16 values, 
# the first value is of sensor 1, the last of sensor 16
input_data = [200,266,350,480,
              247,270,320,511,
              299,317,410,500,
              360,360,504,632]

# create a coordinate grid
x,y = np.meshgrid(range(4), range(4))
z = np.array(input_data).reshape(4,4)

ax = plt.gcf().add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
#plot the values as 3D surface plot 
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!that helped me a lot..really!! but instead of using bar3d plot..is it also possible to make a 3d surface plot with these data?? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but it's not really readable, looking at the plot, who would guess that this plots 16 different sensor data? Of course it's your choice.